# Does every type in .net inherit from System.Object?

Tags: c#, .net

This might be a very basic question, but I am a bit confused about it.
If I reflect the Int32/Double/any value type code, I see that they are structs and look like :

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), ComVisible(true)]
public struct Double : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<double>, IEquatable<double>
{
....
}
```

So, why do we say that everything in .NET is derived from System.Object. I think am missing some crucial point here.

**EDIT:**
What confuses me further is that how can a value type which is struct inherit from System.Object which is a class.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Eric Lippert has covered this in a blog entry: [Not everything derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) (This is the title of the blog entry; **not the answer to this question**. Don't get confused.)

Yes, all `struct`s inherit from `System.ValueType` which in turn inherits from `System.Object`. `enum`s you declare inherit from `System.Enum` which inherits from `System.ValueType`.

#### Update:

Inherently, there's not a problem with a value type being derived from a reference type. Inheritance is a "is-a" relationship between two *types*. However, in order to treat a value type as an object instance, it has to be boxed. This is done implicitly when you are passing a value to a method that expects an object parameter (or when you call instance methods implemented in `System.Object`.)

Comment: And I just linked that entry in another post ...

Comment: great link...but this has confused me more. Eric says 'All value types, including enums and nullable types, derive from object...'

Comment: Enums and structs inherit from `System.ValueType` which in turn inherits from `System.Object`.

Comment: @Mehrdad You say Enums and structs inherit from System.ValueType. Where can I see this ? I can't see this using reflector.

Comment: PK: You can see using .NET Reflector and `ildasm.exe`. In Reflector, go to mscorlib > System > Int32, Enum, ... > Base Types and you'll see System.ValueType.

Comment: Now this means that every type in .net is in fact a class. My head is now spinning.
Also, I can see Enum, but not struct using the reflector.

Comment: @PK: You can see it using reflector if you swith to IL.

Comment: @Mehrdad '...and structs you write in code are a structs'. What does this mean?

Comment: PK: Comment formatting screwed that up. I'll repost it.

Comment: PK: `struct` itself is not a type. For instance, Int32, Double, and structs you write in code are types that directly from System.ValueType. Each enums you declare is also a separate type that inherits from `System.Enum` which inherits from System.ValueType.

Answer (score 8):

Not every type, but System.Double does.

From Eric Lippert's post:

> All value types, including enums and
>   nullable types, derive from object

In C# struct is syntatic sugar for System.ValueType, meaning that System.Double derives from System.ValueType.
Since System.ValueType derives from System.Object, System.Double does too.
You can see that using the .Net Framework source code or using .Net Reflector:

```
.class public sequential ansi serializable sealed beforefieldinit Double
    extends System.ValueType
```

**UPDATE:**

On the toolbar, if you select C#, you'll see (This is what you are seeing):
[alt text http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pk3EAm_SJtl4dn51HLrhdgHAXCS08-xY9nQUARCpT4WnBQyRHD4RLmIK9zZ4okJXMj7Xopg1EBuY_Od7_oWz7Pw/DoubleCSharp.jpg](http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pk3EAm_SJtl4dn51HLrhdgHAXCS08-xY9nQUARCpT4WnBQyRHD4RLmIK9zZ4okJXMj7Xopg1EBuY_Od7_oWz7Pw/DoubleCSharp.jpg)

**If you change the ComboBox and select IL then you'll see:**
[alt text http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pRXk-0rDvFjj7b8EqU9-bydzpWjVGJMq8pDbiCr6aALob3j-aC9vvbeBS4vQRedHJ5Dh2CWtYRCywMJ9FGHOaaw/DoubleIL.jpg](http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pRXk-0rDvFjj7b8EqU9-bydzpWjVGJMq8pDbiCr6aALob3j-aC9vvbeBS4vQRedHJ5Dh2CWtYRCywMJ9FGHOaaw/DoubleIL.jpg)

See that in IL, Double extends System.ValueType

Comment: Its not just Double, it is all the basic types such as int, short, long, decimal etc - that derive from System.ValueType.

Comment: I do know that. I happend to use Double as an example he did.

Comment: Double is a struct. How can it derive from System.ValueType. Also, I can see the code of Double. It just implements interfaces.

Comment: @PK: Please read the answer. If you look at the IL instead of metadata or the code decompiled into C#, you'll see that Double inherits from ValueType. 

From the C# spec: 

Structs are value types ($11.3.1)

All struct types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType ($11.3.2).

Answer (score 4):

Just few weeks ago [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) blogged about this: [Not everything derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx). A great read.

Answer (score 3):

As far as your question is concerned, structs inherit from [ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) *implicitly*, which in turn derives from object.

Other than that, Eric Lippert's link posted above is what you would like to read.