# Do value types (Integer, Decimal, Boolean, etc...) inherit from Object?

Tags: .net

Looking for clarification on this...

I've heard that 'everything' in .Net inherits from Object.  I've also heard that the difference between value types and reference types is that reference types inherit from Object and value types do not.

My understanding was that everything was an object (inherits from System.Object); but value types and reference types were simply 'different' from one another.  Value types are allocated on the stack and reference types get a 'pointer' placed on the Stack that points to an address on the Heap.

Is that the gist of it?  What makes an Integer a value type?  That's something inherent in the language?

Comment: "What makes an Integer a value type" - CLR "knows" about primitive value types and handles them specially, it is not specific inherent in the language (say C#)

Comment: Value types are not necessarily allocated on the stack. Consider a value type field in a class - instance of that class would be on the heap, and therefore so would be the field. In fact, the whole allocation issue is strictly an implementation detail - value types have value semantics and no inherent object identity (so no `==`, for example), and that's all there is to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does every type in .net inherit from System.Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316626/does-every-type-in-net-inherit-from-system-object)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Value types, such as `Int32`, are structs.

From the VS 2008 C# help file (since I had it open) on structs:

> A struct cannot inherit from another struct or class, and it cannot be the base of a class. All structs inherit directly from System.ValueType, which inherits from System.Object.

Answer (score 22):

It depends on how you view the terminology - which depends on whether you're talking about C# or the CLI spec. For example, in the CLI spec (ECMA-355) sections 8.9.8 and 8.9.10 state:

> Value types do not inherit, although
>   the associated boxed type is an object
>   type and hence inherits from other
>   types.

and

> In their unboxed form value types do
>   not inherit from any type. Boxed value
>   types shall inherit directly from
>   `System.ValueType` unless they are
>   enumerations, in which case, they
>   shall inherit from `System.Enum`. Boxed
>   value types shall be sealed.

So from the CLI's point of view, the answer to the question is **no**.

However, let's look at the C# spec - and as we're in an ECMA-like mood, let's go for that version (which is currently stuck at C# 2). Section 11.1.1 states:

> All value types implicitly inherit
>   from the class `System.ValueType`,
>   which, in turn, inherits from class
>   `object`.

So from the C# specification's point of view, the answer is **yes**.

One could argue that you tagged your question ".net" so we should use the CLI definition; if you'd tagged it "c#" we should have used the C# definition. See how arbitrary it is? :)

All of this spec-diving isn't to much practical purpose though. The answer depends on the intricacies of definitions. It's more sensible to construct some interesting situation where it matters... so what do you want to do? If you can present some code, we can answer questions about what will happen - and that's more important than definitions.

(Yes, this is unusual for me - in general, terminology matters a lot to me. In some cases, however, the subtleties are more of a curse than a blessing.)

Comment: Man, you need to get out more :D

Comment: @Ben: "More" suggests I currently get out at all ;)

Comment: LOL, well at least you got one outing this year to DevDays ;)

Answer (score 6):

According to [Red Gate's .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) they inherit (indirectly) from object.

- Object -> ValueType -> int32
- Object -> ValueType -> boolean
- Object -> ValueType -> decimal
- Object -> ValueType -> byte
- Object -> ValueType -> char
- Object -> ValueType -> uint32

I haven't checked other types, but it would seem they do.  I would highly recommend getting Reflector - it's a free download and it will help you answer countless other questions about how various parts of the .NET framework are coded.  Some days I wonder how I'd live without it.

The greatest thing about Reflector is that you don't need to rely on someone's potentially outdated (or incorrect or badly interpreted) writing to discover what is *really* going on inside the .NET Framework - including that on MSDN - not even the almighty Microsoft is infallible.  The documentation is only as current as its last modification.  Getting your answers directly from the code is the least likely to be incorrect - assuming of course that you're able to correctly interpet said code ;)

Answer (score 4):

Value types also inherit from `Object`, but not directly. They inherit from [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx), which in turn inherits `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

value types inherit (indirectly) from object

... but [not everything in .net inherits from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx).

Comment: Every type *does* inherit from Object.

Comment: Or maybe I should say that every type *conforms to* Object.

Comment: Apart from interfaces, pointer types (e.g. `int*`) do not inherit from `Object`. Also, if you step down one level from C# to CLR, then CLR has two kinds of pointer types - unmanaged and managed, `int*` and `int&` - neither of which inherits from `Object` (the latter kind is seen as `ref` in C# when used for a function parameter, and is not accessible in any other context).

Comment: Interesting, didn't know this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, value types do inherit from Object.

See the *Inheritance Hierarchy* section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx

The *Remarks* section in the same page says, literally:

> Both reference and value types are
>   derived from the ultimate base class
>   Object.

Answer (score 2):

In short, not quite everything derives from `object`, there are exceptions. This blog post from Eric Lippert is probably the best reference on this topic: ["Not everything derives from object"](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx)

All `struct`s implicitly derive from `System.ValueType`.

The difference between value types and reference types is a semantical issue: value types exhibit value semantics while reference types exhibit value semantics. Implementation details (such as where they are allocated etc. are not important).

`int`s, for example, are value types because they are `struct`s. Of course, we model `int`s as value types because they represent values and we want value semantics, not reference semantics.

Comment: @Downvoter: Really? You have some explaining to do before I whip you boy.

Answer (score 2):

from MSDN: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Value Types

The value types consist of two main categories:

```
* Struct type
* Enumeration type
```

The struct types contain the user-defined struct types and the following built-in simple types:

```
* Numeric types
      o Integral types
      o Floating-point types
      o decimal
* bool
```

**Main Features of Value Types**

A variable of a value type always contains a value of that type. The assignment to a variable of a value type creates a copy of the assigned value, while the assignment to a variable of a reference type creates a copy of the reference but not of the referenced object.

All value types are derived implicitly from the Object class.

Unlike reference types, it is not possible to derive a new type from a value type. However, like reference types, structs can implement interfaces.

Unlike reference types, it is not possible for a value type to contain the null value.

Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type. For information on default values of value types, see Default Values Table.

**Main Features of Simple Types**

All of the simple types are aliases of the .NET Framework System types. For example, int is an alias of System.Int32. For a complete list of aliases, see Built-in Types Table.

Constant expressions, whose operands are all simple type constants, are evaluated at compilation time. For more information, see 7.15 Constant expressions.

Simple types can be initialized using literals. For example, 'A' is a literal of the type char and 2001 is a literal of the type int.