# Add Integer[] to list<Object>

Tags: c#, .net, list

Question: Why can't i add an `Array of Integers` to a `List<Object>`?

following the posts:

[do-value-types-integer-decimal-boolean-etc-inherit-from-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793357/do-value-types-integer-decimal-boolean-etc-inherit-from-object)

[how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes)

i'm understanding the following structure:

```
Integer => Inherits => System.ValueType => Inherits => System.Object
```

Then why am i getting an error when i do the following:

```
 List<object> myObjects = new List<object>();
 myObjects.AddRange(IntegerArray.ToList());
```

**Given Error:**

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>
```

This one works though:

```
 List<int> myObjects = new List<int>();
 myObjects.AddRange(IntegerArray.ToList());
```

Comment: Check this one: [Why covariance and contravariance do not support value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type)

Comment: Just curious, but why a `list<object>`? seems a little bit dangerous to me

Comment: `Addrange` should be `AddRange`, to start with - this clearly isn't your real code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that AddRange expects, as the error message suggests, an `IEnumerable<object>` and you're passing it an `IEnumerable<int>`.  The fact that 'int' derives from object does not mean that `IEnumerable<int>` derives from `IEnumerable<object>`.  If you do this then it will work because you'll be using the correct type:

```
myObjects.AddRange(IntegerArray.Cast<object>());
```

Comment: Sweet! i was incorrect to assume that an implicit cast would occur. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitely say how to convert these types to each other by for example using ConvertAll, as explained here: [convert a list of objects from one type to another using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression).

The advantage is that it's potentially possible to convert any type.

Also look for [contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) to have an explanation on why this is: a `List<Type1>` cannot be casted to a `List<Type2>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting?

```
List<object> myObjects = new List<object>();
myObjects.AddRange(IntegerArray.ToList().Cast<object>());
```

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, hm. Should probably have tested first ;-) thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not adding *an array* to the `List<object>`, but rather *attempting to add each element in the array individually*.

You can certainly do this, which is how the question title reads to me:

```
List<object> myObjects = new List<object>();
myObjects.Add(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

However your code tells a different story, and it fails because of signature incompatibility between `AddRange` and the type you use to pass to it. If you have an `int[]` and want to add its contents to the list individually, use `Cast`:

```
myObjects.AddRange((new[] { 1, 2, 3 }).Cast<object>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Co/Contravariance aren't allowed in C# at a collection/generics level. 
i.e. assignment of `List<int>` to `List<object>`

Answer (score 0):

> int is not object type it's primitive type.
>   So to convert it to Object, first you need to convert it to Integer, it's wrapper 
>       class, then convert it to Object.
>
> Also, This code requires typecasting twice.
>   First from int to Integer. then Integer to Object which can not be done implicitly.
>   implicit typecasting can be done by compiler only once. So it needs explicit typecasting in Object type.