# Are instances and objects the same thing?

Tags: c#, oop, object, instance, new-operator

I keep hearing the words `instances` and `objects`, don't they have the same meaning or not?

For example, if I want to initialize an object of a class, I use the `new` operator to initialize an object with a class.

```
Button button = new Button();
```

> I have an object or instance now, don't I?

Comment: In practical terms, `instance` and `object` are synonymous.

Comment: Not quite. In C# and the CLR's case you can actually have an instance of an unboxed valuetype, which is not an object. You can also have an instance of a ref pointer.

Comment: @Charlieface Why is an unboxed valuetype not an object?

Comment: An object is something that inherits from `System.Object`. Only a boxed valuetype does, not an unboxed one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793357/do-value-types-integer-decimal-boolean-etc-inherit-from-object @Charlieface Regardless, `object` when talking in general terms is not talking about `System.Object` _specifically_.

Comment: @mjwills I guess I come more from the CLI/CLR perspective, that an object will be on the heap. The second top answer there shows up the difference.

Comment: I know @Charlieface - hence why I suggested the link. You don't need to explain it to me. ;) Regardless, `object` when talking in general terms is not talking about `System.Object` _specifically_. Thus, for someone learning programming the answer to `I keep hearing the words instances and objects, don't they have the same meaning or not?` is - in practical terms they are synonymous.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a pleasure to communicate with you.

Comment: A class is a class like a recipe. An instance is an instance of a class like a cake. Object is abiguous and can mean either.

Comment: @SandraJames **An object is an instance of a class**. A class is the concept of the chair in the mind. The instance is the fact that a chair exists in the real word and is different from another chair. The object is the chair itself. Therefore an instance is a concretization or materialization of a class idea, and we call that an object. So we say that instance and object words are synonymous, keeping in mind this subtlety of the vocabulary.