# Why `IEnumerable<int>` is not `IEnumerable<object>`?

Tags: c#, covariance

`IEnumerable<T>` interface is covariant, so `IEnumerable<string>` is `IEnumerable<object>`.
But why `IEnumerable<int>` is ***not*** `IEnumerable<object>` while `int` is `object`?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces: "Variance in generic interfaces is supported for reference types only. Value types do not support variance. For example, `IEnumerable<int>` cannot be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<object>`, because integers are represented by a value type."

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793357/do-value-types-integer-decimal-boolean-etc-inherit-from-object, but it's basically int's are structs not objects

Comment: Or if you want a spec reference: https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/interfaces.md#17233-variance-conversion - the important part being "and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from Aᵢ to Bᵢ" - there's no *reference or identity* conversion from `int` to `object`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do value types (Integer, Decimal, Boolean, etc...) inherit from Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793357/do-value-types-integer-decimal-boolean-etc-inherit-from-object)

Comment: If it helps, [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) implements `IEnumerable`. So if you're looking for a common interface, both `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<string>` are `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Now with docs linked by @JonSkeet should we convert this question "why C#/.Net decided to limit variance to reference types" or write wiki answer with 100% text from the docs (which is not really suitable for SO)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance conversions like this are only supported if there is an implicit *reference* or *identity* conversion between the type parameters. As the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#17233-variance-conversion) says:

> A type `T<Aᵢ, ..., Aᵥ>` is variance-convertible to a type `T<Bᵢ, ..., Bᵥ>` if `T` is either an interface or a delegate type declared with the variant type parameters `T<Xᵢ, ..., Xᵥ>`, and for each variant type parameter `Xᵢ` one of the following holds:
>
> - `Xᵢ` is covariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Aᵢ` to `Bᵢ`
> - `Xᵢ` is contravariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Bᵢ` to `Aᵢ`
> - `Xᵢ` is invariant and an identity conversion exists from `Aᵢ` to `Bᵢ`

There is neither a reference not identity conversion between `int` and `object`, only a *boxing* conversion.

You might be wondering what's so special about implicit reference and identity conversions, that they allow variance conversions. Well, these conversions don't require the runtime to do anything at all!

To convert from a `string` to `object`, for example, is purely a compile-time matter. Nothing needs to be done to the bits representing the `string`, in order to turn it into an `object`. After all, every `string` is an `object`.

Because of this, converting from `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>` is trivial too - the runtime does not need to do anything.

This is not true for the `int`-to-`object` conversion, however. Because `int` is a value type and `object` is a reference type. to maintain these semantics, the runtime needs to create a reference type wrapper around that `int` in order to do the conversion, "boxing" it.

This means that the runtime cannot just "do nothing" if it wants to convert a `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>`. You would expect to get reference types out of that `IEnumerable`, not value types, so when and how does the "boxing" happen? When and how should this happen *in general*, not just in the case of `IEnumerable<T>`?

I'm sure this in theory can all be figured out, designed, and implemented, but it would certainly not be as trivial as the case with implicit reference conversions. In fact, I reckon it would be a lot more complicated and very drastic changes to both the language and runtime would be needed, which is probably why this is not implemented.