# Value Type, Reference Type and Boxing

Tags: c#

I know there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316626/does-every-type-in-net-inherit-from-system-object?noredirect=1&lq=1) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object?noredirect=1&lq=1) questions covering this topic and I have read them all. But I'm still left wondering this:

If an `object` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and all value types are [derived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) from `object`, then is it accurate to say that a value type such as `int` is also a reference type? Specifically, if I wrote:

```
int i = 10;
```

Is `i` holding the value of 10, or is it an object holding a reference to the value of 10?

Or is it more accurate to say that a value type *can* be a reference type through the process of boxing.

Comment: You shouldn't just read the questions, you should also read the answers. :)  Also read the [links](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/) that people provided in the answers. I don't see how this isn't a duplicate of the questions you linked to in your first sentence.

Comment: I did read the answers. I actually spent several hours reading the answers. I just needed more clarification and I guess this wasn’t the right forum. Although I did get that clarification below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it accurate to say that a value type such as int is also a reference type? 
>   …Or is it more accurate to say that a value type can be a reference type through the process of boxing.

Neither is accurate. `int` is a value type, period. It is not "also a reference type". And when boxed, it's not magically changed to be a reference type. The `System.Object` that contains it is a reference type, but inside is still the *value* of the *value type* `int`.

> Is i holding the value of 10, or is it an object holding a reference to the value of 10?

See above. `i` has the type `int`, which is a value type, and so the variable contains the *value* you've assigned to it, `10`.

See also [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057267)

Comment: +1. You might also want to add the link to [ValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: @PeterDuniho "The System.Object that contains it is a reference type, but inside is still the value of the value type int" - this is exactly what I needed to know.  Thank you for clarifying.